# select all check box in android listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox, multiple-choice

In my Application,  i tried to create a list with multiple check boxes.

for that i tried one `ListView` with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` for multiple choice in `ListView`.

My ListView in XML as,..

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="468dp"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
```

And i use an `CheckBox` to select/deselect all the `CheckBox` in the `ListView` as

```
   <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/select_all"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="Select all" />
```

and java code as,..

```
selectall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int size = 0;
            boolean isChecked = selectall.isChecked();
            if (isChecked == true) {
                size = getListView().getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
                    l1.setItemChecked(i, true);
            } else if(isChecked==false)
            {
                size = getListView().getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
                    l1.setItemChecked(i, false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here i have assigned the l1 as my `ListView`. Now my Select All check box working very well for Select/Deselect all the check boxes in the `ListView`.

But, if i deselect one of the item after clicking select all check box, its not un-checking..

And if i select all the check boxes in the list manually means, the Select all `CheckBox` needs to checked automatically..

I used the following codes for ListAdapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>
       (this,Android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,list);
     setListAdapter(adapter1);
     l1=getListView();
```

I'm trying to achieve this Solution..

Comment: Listen for the check box change event for the text boxes inside the list

Comment: How could we set Listen for the checkboxes in the List?

Comment: Add click listener for the checkboxes inside the list.

Comment: save the check box state and write onclick listener for each click and check with saved state

Comment: Its not a customized ListView... Check my Updated Question.. I used Android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice in my ListView

Answer (score 1):

you could use a HashMap or a List of **theObjectRow** to keep track of which sheckbox is checked with a boolean.

then when you click on **checkAll** you update all boolean in your list to true and do yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

of course in your adapter (baseadapter for example) you use the HashMap/List in GetView to init the cells.

```
if(list.get(position).isChecked()){
    cellHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
}
else{
    cellHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
}
```

All the boolean are at true so all the checkBox ll be checked (the same logic goes for uncheck)

hope it help
good luck